# Access "Must use updatable query" when trying to Insert new record

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have the following problem, I am getting a "Must use updateable query" when trying to insert a new record into an Access Database.

The code is:

```
OleDbConnection Conn = new
OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=Checkbook.accdb;");
string SQL = "Insert into Category (CategoryDescription) values('Pizza')"
OpenDatabase(); //This does a Conn.Open();
OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQL, Conn);
myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
CloseDatabase();
```

Comment: Assuming that [Category] is a Table (and not a saved Query) it sounds like the process that is running your code only has read access to the database file. Check the permissions on that file *and the folder in which it resides* to ensure that the account running your code will have write permissions on both the file and the folder. (Write access on the folder is required so the Access Database Engine can create the .laccdb lock file.)

Comment: I have the necessary write permission on the file and folder. It is still happening.

Comment: Does the `Category` table has any other fields that are not auto-number and do not allow nulls? Also you need a space after `values`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine as written.  Assuming the missing code in the open and close methods does not do anything unusual.  The error you see can be easily reproduced by setting the file to read only on the file system.  You can verify that in the properties window.

[image: Read Only Database]

If you see the read only check box is checked you can removed it in the properties of the file in windows explorer.

If you don't see the file set to read only here and you have the proper file permissions, see if there is something else locking the file.  You can test this by creating a new access database and recreating the table and pointing your code to the test database.  If the same error occurs, you know you have a global issue on the machine.  If you don't have the same problem, you likely have an issue with the original database.